# Java generic interface implements Object instead of Type T

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I want to create a generic database connection class which handles all the incoming database query for different types of classes.

I've wrote a generic interface

```
public interface IDBConnection<T> {

public void createOrUpdate(T t);
public void delete(T t);

public void initConnection();
public void closeConnection();
}
```

and implemented it into the database connection class

```
public class GenericDBCon implements IDBConnection {

private static JdbcConnectionSource con;


@Override
public void createOrUpdate(Object t) {

}

@Override
public void delete(Object t) {

}

@Override
public void initConnection() {

}

@Override
public void closeConnection() {

}
}
```

I don't understand why the implementation of, lets say the createOrUpdate-function has an "Object t" as parameter instead of "T t" like in definition of the interface?

Comment: You are using `IDBConnection` without a type argument in the line `public class GenericDBCon implements IDBConnection`. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is that you are not including the generic declaration in either of the classes' headers, so it defaults to `Object`.

You will need to change the header of the IDBConnection class to

```
public interface IDBConnection<T>
```

and the header of the `GenericDBCon` class to

```
public class GenericDBCon<T> implements IDBConnection<T>
```

or

```
public class GenericDBCon implements IDBConnection<SomeClass>
```

The second alternative for `GenericDBCon` provides a specific class as the generic, rather than getting one provided by some other piece of code (e.g a variable declaration: `GenericDBCon<MyClass> dbCon = new GenericDBCon<MyClass>`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IDBConnection<T extends Model> {

public void createOrUpdate(T t);
public void delete(T t);

public void initConnection();
public void closeConnection();
}
```

//All classes should extend this interface.

```
public interface Model {
    //Define common table properties here which are used in create and delete
}

public class GenericDBCon<T extends Model> implements IDBConnection<T extends Model> {

private static JdbcConnectionSource con;


@Override
public void createOrUpdate(Model t) {
    //Now it is ensured that the classes are of type model
}

@Override
public void delete(Model t) {

}

@Override
public void initConnection() {

}

@Override
public void closeConnection() {

}
}
```